# Cuando convertir a factor

Tags: r

A parte de para amoldarse a los requisitos de ciertas funciones de R que exigen que los parametros sena de tipo factor cuando es recomendable trabajar con factores?
Es deceir, si una variable tiene solo valores 0 o 1 o Yes o No conviene categorizarlas sin más para posteriores analisis?

En mi caso estoy en un proyecto de machine learning predictivo

Un saludo

Comment: La respuesta es depende, las variables que mencionas sin duda son categóricas, pero no necesariamente necesiten ser tratadas como factores, eso dependerá del análisis que hagas con ellas.

Comment: Hola. Si por ejemplo yo importo un csv con 2 columnas: Jefes de proyecto y Código de Proyecto y luego solo voy a hacer un ranking por cantidad de proyectos que cada uno gestiona pero R me interpreta ambas variables como factor en este caso no voy a necesitar cada uno de los niveles para nada y podría o bien dejarlo así o convertirlos a character no? no se si obtengo alguna ventaja de rendimiento o de algún tipo haciendo la transformación la verdad.

Comment: Habitualmente las cadenas se transforman en factores por una cuestión histórica y que siempre fue discutida en la comunidad de programadores R, de hecho, en la próxima, versión 4, esto dejará de ser así. Una cadena no es necesario tratarla como factor, por que si de algo se puede estar seguro es que no es una variable continua. Los factores reducen sin duda el consumo de memoria, pero a costa de algunos inconvenientes a la hora de usarlos. En mi opinión el uso de factores esta justificado sobretodo con variables numéricas, que son categóricas, ejemplo 1 y 0, puntajes, etc.